# Why "Type of argument to each on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref at test.pl line 17."?

Tags: perl, constants, each

I don't understand the error message

> Type of argument to each on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref at test.pl line 17.

for this test case (extracted from a larger module):

```perl
BEGIN { our $RE_timestamp = qr/whatever/; }

# check Regular expressions for TIMESTAMP
use constant _TEST_TIMESTAMPS => (        # from "6.2.3.1.  Examples"
        '1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z' => 1,
        '1985-04-12T19:20:50.52-04:00' => 1,
        '2003-10-11T22:14:15.003Z' => 1,
        '2003-08-24T05:14:15.000003-07:00' => 1,
        '2003-08-24T05:14:15.000000003-07:00' => 0,        # invalid!
        '-' => 1                        # NILVALUE
);

UNITCHECK
{

    # from "6.2.3.1.  Examples"
    while (my ($str, $valid) = each _TEST_TIMESTAMPS) {
        if ($valid) {
            die "timestamp ($str) is not valid\n"
                if ($str !~ /^${RE_timestamp}$/o);
        } else {
            die "timestamp ($str) is valid\n"
                if ($str =~ /^${RE_timestamp}$/o);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of all I got the error in Perl 5.18.2, but when I checked on another machine using Perl 5.26.1, there was no error message at all!

So can I make the code work with the older Perl 5.18, too?

### Ugly Work-Around

Experimenting I found out that `each (my %h = _TEST_TIMESTAMPS)` did not help, but when using `my %h = _TEST_TIMESTAMPS;` and then `each %h`, then the error was gone.

Still I don't understand what's going on (before using constants I had local `my` hashes used inside `UNITCHECK`.
Obviously I'd like to use package-level constants instead.

Comment: Why not just replace the constant with a variable? If you're worried about forgetting not to change it, just name it `$CONSTANT{timestamps}`.

Comment: @TLP Can do both, having a variable and having it be readonly, using `Const::Fast` or `Readonly` (and there are yet others), as in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `_TEST_TIMESTAMPS` is given as a "[list constant](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant#List-constants)" in the question and will behave only as a flat list, not as a hash.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71804896/4653379) for a very detailed discussion. Also, as such it is rejected by `each` as the error message informs us.

One can use a hash-reference instead

```
use constant _TEST_TIMESTAMPS => { ... };
```

and this is accepted by `each`.  It appears to work correctly for the question's snippet but I'd be careful with more involved use. Using references with `constant` comes with its own issues.

Also, keep in mind that objects from [constant pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.005/constant#TECHNICAL-NOTE) are really subroutines ("*in the current implementation*", as docs say); see `Technical Note` and `Bugs`. This can affect what one should expect of their behavior in various circumstances.

One the other hand, swapping `const` for, say, `Const::Fast`, makes it work cleanly under all circumstances with normal lexical variables

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Const::Fast;

our $RE_timestamp;    
BEGIN { our $RE_timestamp = qr/whatever/; }

# check Regular expressions for TIMESTAMP
our %_TEST_TIMESTAMPS;
BEGIN {
    const our %_TEST_TIMESTAMPS => (        # from "6.2.3.1.  Examples"
        '1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z' => 1,
        '1985-04-12T19:20:50.52-04:00' => 1,
        '2003-10-11T22:14:15.003Z' => 1,
        '2003-08-24T05:14:15.000003-07:00' => 1,
        '2003-08-24T05:14:15.000000003-07:00' => 0,        # invalid!
        '-' => 1                        # NILVALUE
    );  
}

UNITCHECK
{
    # from "6.2.3.1.  Examples"
    while (my ($str, $valid) = each %_TEST_TIMESTAMPS) {
        if ($valid) {
            die "timestamp ($str) is not valid\n"
                if ($str !~ /^${RE_timestamp}$/o);
        } else {
            die "timestamp ($str) is valid\n"
                if ($str =~ /^${RE_timestamp}$/o);
        }
    }
}
```

Lexicals introduced with `Const::Fast` must be assigned at declaration (and of course cannot be reassigned later), so here that has to be an `our` variable as it need be assigned inside of a `BEGIN` block but declared outside of it, so to be set *and* visible for `UNITCHECK`.<sup>†</sup>

I use [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) merely as my preference; another viable library is [Readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Readonly).

Note that `$RE_timestamp` must be first lexically declared outside of any blocks if `strict` is to be used (and why wouldn't one use it?). I corrected that.  It need not be `our` for any of this but I leave that since there may be other reasons for it.

As for why this isn't an issue in later Perls, I suppose that the requirement for it to be a hashref or arrayref got dropped at some point. (I can't check that right now.)

---

<sup>†</sup> That we can formally declare a variable at multiple places is a property of the lexical alias of a global variable, [our](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be `each` insisting on a hash *variable* (not a constant), so I solved it like this (not genuine, but it works):

```perl
UNITCHECK
{
    my $hr = { _TEST_TIMESTAMPS };
    while (my ($str, $valid) = each %$hr) {
        #...
    }
}
```

However a new temporary hash will be created by `{ _TEST_TIMESTAMPS }`, so it might be better to assign a hash reference to the constant instead.
Then you'd still need a variable, but no temporary hash object would be created.