# How can I pass a reference of an array defined as constant?

Tags: perl, constants

I defined hash and array constants, When passing those to a function, I'll have to pass them as references.
However I'm wondering what the correct syntax is.

Consider this example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant AC => qw(a b c);

sub f($)
{
    print "ref=", ref $_[0], "\n";
    print "$_\n" foreach (@{$_[0]});
}

f(\AC);
```

When I run it I get:

```text
ref=SCALAR
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at /run/media/whatever/constref.pl line 10.
```

The Perl debugger prints `AC` as an array:

```perl
13: f(\AC);
  DB<1> x AC
0  'a'
1  'b'
2  'c'
  DB<2> c
```

Comment: @Dave Cross Sorry, you were right. I messed up my test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [List Constants](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant#List-constants) section in the [constant pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant) docs tells us that

> Constants may be lists of more (or less) than one value.
> ...
> List constants are lists, not arrays.

This means, among other properties, that one *cannot* take a reference of that "list constant" as if it were a single entity, like an array variable is; it behaves as a list, a group of scalars.<sup>†</sup>

In order to accomplish what is asked then we need to build an (anonymous) array reference out of that list and pass that, `f([AC])`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use constant AC => qw(a b c);

sub f {
    my ($r) = @_;
    say "ref=", ref $r;
    say for @$r;
}

f( [ AC ] );
```

This passes the "list constant" as a single value, an array reference, and it prints as expected. However, I don't like having to copy values, nor to further lose any semblance of constant-ness.<sup>‡</sup>  There are other ways to do this but those are even less palatable to me.<sup>§</sup>

I'd suggest to reconsider the tool to use when proper read-only variables are needed.

There are other libraries for this and I'd recommend [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast), or [Readonly](https://metacpan.org/pod/Readonly).

```
use Const::Fast;    
const my @const_ary => qw(a b c);
f( \@const_ary );                 # same f() from above

use Readonly;
Readonly my @carr => qw(a b c);
f( \@carr );                      # same f() from above
```

These are lexical variables that one can handle like any other.  See docs.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Attempting to formally "take a reference" of a list results in a list of references

```
\($v, $t)  -->  \$v, \$t
```

---

<sup>‡</sup> While the `AC` itself is a constant, the list that it is associated with [isn't read-only](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant#NOTES)

```
use constant AC => qw(a b c);

(AC)[1] = "other";

say for AC;
```

prints

```
a
other
c
```

They're just not constant.

---

<sup>§</sup>  I can see two other ways

- The [constant pragma produces (is implemented as) a *subroutine*](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant#CAVEATS). Then one *could* use that and pass it as such, `f(\&AC)`, and then use it as such, `say for $r->()`.

  However, now we have to pass and dereference a subroutine off of that list symbol (`AC`), and get a list. This is a really bad hack.
- The code in the question uses a "constant list."  One can use a reference instead and that can be passed as such

  ```
  use constant AC => [ qw(a b c) ];

  # same sub f { } as above

  f( AC );  # prints as expected
  ```

  However, I don't see how to dereference `AC` to get the whole list (`@{ AC }` doesn't go?), apart from copying it to an arrayref first, like in `f()`.  But then that defies the purpose of having it as a `constant` -- and all [pretense to constant-ness](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant#TECHNICAL-NOTES) is dropped.

Comment: On "*List constants are lists, not arrays*": So both are ordered, indexed and finite (which qualifies them as "array" for me), but the difference seems to be that (in C speak) that lists are no "lvalues", and references require an lvalue. However I've seen code like `my $r = \1;`. Trying that on a list seems to evaluate it as scalar, giving a reference to a scalar (which is the number of list items). Tricky, isn't it?

Comment: A great answer! As `Const::Fast` isn't shipped with my OS, I don't want to add another dependency. Unfortunately my OS also lacks the description for `Readonly` in Perl 5.18.2, even though it is mentioned in "SEE ALSO" of `man 3pm constant`. I guess it's a bug in the OS (SlES12 SP5).

Comment: I found out that I had to install a separate package (`perl-Readonly`) in SLES12 SP5. My previous guess was that it is included in the core package if available.

Comment: @U.Windl Heh, yes, it's tricky.  The thing here is, a list isn't a variable; it is literally a list of scalars (on the stack), rather elusive and ephemeral. So "taking a reference" of _that_ doesn't really make sense -- and one gets a list with a reference of each.  (Usually not what one meant :). But yes one can do `\1` etc.  I'll look for some (of the many) posts which discuss list-vs-array tomorrow (it's late here now), it's quite interesting.

Comment: @U.Windl Glad if the answer helped!  Good that you can do `Readonly`, it's much easier for use than `constant`, and "normal" (just variables).

Comment: @U.Windl On lists-vs-arrays -- here is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6023821/4653379) as some food for thought, with a few really nice posts.  It turns out [a Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array) on this is good as well. In short, I'd say that lists are syntax features, ways to write/organize code, and a way for perl to move data (values on the stack).  An array is a variable, data type/storage with a fixed (more or less) memory location.  There are a lot of good statements on this, scattered around

Comment: @U.Windl They often behave similarly, and an array in expressions is (internally) often first evaluated into a list and then manipulated. But there are many differences in behavior as they are very different things. The case you bring up is a great example. With my `@ary = (2,3,4); my $r = \@ary;` that `$r` is, well, a reference to a variable (array). But with my `$r = \(2,3,4);` this goes: the reference-operator \ goes through the `()`  (what else?) and, since the `=` operator is in scalar context, the comma operator evaluates one after another (with \ acting on each) ... and `$r` gets `\4`