# How to use `our` class variables with `UNITCHECK` correctly with `use strict`?

Tags: perl, variables, strict

As Perl constants are somewhat strange to use, I decided to implement my "class variables" as `our` variables, just like:

```perl
our $foo = '...';
```

However when I added a `UNITCHECK` block using the class variables, I realized that the variables were not set yet, so I changed the code to:

```perl
BEGIN {
   our $foo = '...';
}

UNITCHECK {
    if ($foo eq 'bla') {
        #...
    }
}
```

Then I realized that I had mistyped some variable names in `UNITCHECK`, so I decided to add `use warnings` and `use strict`.
Unfortunately I'm getting new errors like

> Variable "$foo" is not imported at .. line ..

When I initialize the variable outside `BEGIN`, then the error is away, but then I have the original problem back.

So I wonder:
Is `our $var = 'value';` the remommended and correct use, or should it be split in `our $var;` outside the `BEGIN` and `$var = 'value;` inside `BEGIN`?

As my list of variables is rather long, I'm trying to avoid list them twice (introducing the possibility of misspelling some again).

What is the recommended correct way to do it?

Comment: See also [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71779113/4653379) for most of what is asked, including libraries for constants in Perl, like `Const::Fast` and `Readonly` (on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71804896/4653379) as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`our` is lexically scoped so in your code the variable only exists in the `BEGIN` block. You will need to separate out the declaration from the assignment like this:

```
our $foo;
BEGIN {
    $foo = '...';
}

UNITCHECK {
    if ($foo eq 'bla') {
        #...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `my` would work just as well here and should therefore be used instead of `our`. There's almost no reason to ever use `our`. A notable exception is Exporter's vars.

Comment: Well the code is part of a package, so I guess `my` won't do for class/package-level "constants" (that's what the `our` variable actually are). Also, as the list of such variables is rather long, it makes the "structure" of the code rather ugly (having to declare the long list, but not being able to initialize, and the initialize that list of variables).